# Why do we use [].join here?

Tags: javascript

Why do we use `[].join()` in this way?

```
function printArgs() {
    arguments.join = [].join; 
    var argStr = arguments.join(':'); 
    alert( argStr );
}
printArgs(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: because `arguments`  is no array, but just an array like object.

Comment: note: the first two lines in the function can also be written in a single statement ... `var argStr = [].join.call(arguments, ':');`

Comment: but what does [] mean here?like we are copying args like array in empty[]?

Comment: `[].join` is equivalent to `Array.prototype.join` ... effectively you're creating a new array, then getting the join function from it's prototype

Comment: didnt study prototypes yet...anyway,thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

Because `arguments` object is Array-like object but it is not real array and it doesn't have array properties (like `join` in your example) except `.length`. So in your code you are copying `.join` method from array to arguments object.

Answer (score 0):

The `argument` object is an local variable `array like object` which is available in all functions.

So  `arguments.join = [].join;` is creating a new array and on which you can use all methods that are available in js array.

Therefore `var argStr = arguments.join(':');` will return  `1:2:3`

```
var argStr = arguments.join();      // assigns '1,2,3' to argStr 
var argStr = arguments.join(' + '); // assigns '1 + 2 + 3' to argStr
                          // ^ ^       Note empty space here & in assigned value
var argStr = arguments.join('');  // assigns 123 to argStr
```

Comment: *"is creating a new array and on which you can use all methods that are available in js array"* – That's either not really true or misleading.